# Sorting two tables according to average over past 30 days

Tags: php, mysql

I've turned to your insight for a long time in solving my coding challenges.  I am finally stumped and, after 12 hours of trying, must turn to the gurus with a question of my own.  I'd appreciate any direction you may offer.

I have two mysql tables; POLLS table has a list of polls and DATA table is the data in those polls.  I am trying to list the candidates in an order determined by their average over the past 30 days.

table POLLS

```
poll_id  |  poll_name  |  poll_date
_________|_____________|___________
6        |   poll 6    | 2015-08-22
5        |   poll 5    | 2015-08-14
4        |   poll 4    | 2015-08-09
3        |   poll 3    | 2015-08-02
2        |   poll 2    | 2015-07-28
1        |   poll 1    | 2015-07-20
```

table DATA

```
data_id | data_key | candidate | percent
________|__________|___________|________
1       |   1      |   Joe     |  18
2       |   1      |   Sue     |  19
3       |   1      |   Joy     |  15
4       |   1      |   Tim     |  16
5       |   2      |   Joe     |  20
6       |   2      |   Sue     |  19
7       |   2      |   Joy     |  19
8       |   2      |   Tim     |  22
9       |   3      |   Joe     |  14
10      |   3      |   Sue     |  16
11      |   3      |   Joy     |  21
12      |   3      |   Tim     |  15
13      |   4      |   Joe     |  14
14      |   4      |   Sue     |  15
15      |   4      |   Joy     |  20
16      |   4      |   Tim     |  15
17      |   5      |   Joe     |  17
18      |   5      |   Sue     |  14
19      |   5      |   Joy     |  15
20      |   5      |   Tim     |  16
21      |   6      |   Joe     |  17
22      |   6      |   Sue     |  19
23      |   6      |   Joy     |  16
24      |   6      |   Tim     |  18
```

This is the table result I was looking for.  It contains the poll percent as in table DATA, but the candidates are listed in an order based on the average percent over the past 30 days.

```
candidate | poll 6 | poll 5 | poll 4 | poll 3 | poll 2
__________|________|________|________|________|_______
Joy       | 16     | 15     | 20     | 21     | 19
Tim       | 18     | 16     | 15     | 15     | 22
Sue       | 19     | 14     | 15     | 16     | 19
Joe       | 17     | 17     | 14     | 14     | 20
```

I'm so mixed up that I don't even know where to start anymore.  I've tried lots of possibilities but can only get them to order according to candidate name.

Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: It sounds like you need a dynamic pivot.  Google "mysql dynamic pivot".

Comment: Thankfully, this is tagged with `php`, so you can steer clear of a dynamic pivot.

Comment: Is a poll_id a bit like a data_key?

Comment: Hi.  Yes the data_key column ties the data to a specific poll_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS polls;

CREATE TABLE polls
(poll_id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,poll_name  VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,poll_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO polls VALUES
(6        ,'poll 6','2015-08-22'),
(5        ,'poll 5','2015-08-14'),
(4        ,'poll 4','2015-08-09'),
(3        ,'poll 3','2015-08-02'),
(2        ,'poll 2','2015-07-28'),
(1        ,'poll 1','2015-07-20');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data;

CREATE TABLE data
(data_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,poll_id INT NOT NULL
,candidate VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,percent INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO data VALUES
( 1,1,'Joe',18),
( 2,1,'Sue',19),
( 3,1,'Joy',15),
( 4,1,'Tim',16),
( 5,2,'Joe',20),
( 6,2,'Sue',19),
( 7,2,'Joy',19),
( 8,2,'Tim',22),
( 9,3,'Joe',14),
(10,3,'Sue',16),
(11,3,'Joy',21),
(12,3,'Tim',15),
(13,4,'Joe',14),
(14,4,'Sue',15),
(15,4,'Joy',20),
(16,4,'Tim',15),
(17,5,'Joe',17),
(18,5,'Sue',14),
(19,5,'Joy',15),
(20,5,'Tim',16),
(21,6,'Joe',17),
(22,6,'Sue',19),
(23,6,'Joy',16),
(24,6,'Tim',18);

SELECT d.candidate
     , p.poll_name
     , d.percent
     , 30_day_avg
  FROM polls p
  JOIN data d
    ON d.poll_id = p.poll_id
  JOIN (SELECT candidate, AVG(percent) 30_day_avg FROM polls p JOIN data d ON d.poll_id = p.poll_id WHERE poll_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 day GROUP BY candidate) x
    ON x.candidate = d.candidate
 WHERE p.poll_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 day
 ORDER
    BY 30_day_avg DESC, candidate, p.poll_id DESC;
+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+
| candidate | poll_name | percent | 30_day_avg |
+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+
| Joy       | poll 6    |      16 |    18.2000 |
| Joy       | poll 5    |      15 |    18.2000 |
| Joy       | poll 4    |      20 |    18.2000 |
| Joy       | poll 3    |      21 |    18.2000 |
| Joy       | poll 2    |      19 |    18.2000 |
| Tim       | poll 6    |      18 |    17.2000 |
| Tim       | poll 5    |      16 |    17.2000 |
| Tim       | poll 4    |      15 |    17.2000 |
| Tim       | poll 3    |      15 |    17.2000 |
| Tim       | poll 2    |      22 |    17.2000 |
| Sue       | poll 6    |      19 |    16.6000 |
| Sue       | poll 5    |      14 |    16.6000 |
| Sue       | poll 4    |      15 |    16.6000 |
| Sue       | poll 3    |      16 |    16.6000 |
| Sue       | poll 2    |      19 |    16.6000 |
| Joe       | poll 6    |      17 |    16.4000 |
| Joe       | poll 5    |      17 |    16.4000 |
| Joe       | poll 4    |      14 |    16.4000 |
| Joe       | poll 3    |      14 |    16.4000 |
| Joe       | poll 2    |      20 |    16.4000 |
+-----------+-----------+---------+------------+
```

PHP is unfortunately not my strong suit, but here's an example of how you might transform the array (and thereby 'pivot' that result) in PHP...

```
<?php

require('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');

$query = "
SELECT d.candidate
     , p.poll_name
     , d.percent
     , 30_day_avg
  FROM polls p
  JOIN data d
    ON d.poll_id = p.poll_id
  JOIN (SELECT candidate, AVG(percent) 30_day_avg FROM polls p JOIN data d ON d.poll_id = p.poll_id WHERE poll_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 day GROUP BY candidate) x
    ON x.candidate = d.candidate
 WHERE p.poll_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 30 day
 ORDER
    BY 30_day_avg DESC, candidate, p.poll_id DESC;
";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$old_array = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

$old_array[] = $row;

}

$new_array = array();

foreach( $old_array as $v )
{
    if(!isset( $new_array[$v["candidate"]][$v["poll_name"]]))
    {
       $new_array[$v["candidate"]][($v["poll_name"])] = $v["percent"];
    }
}

print_r($new_array);

?>
```

outputs:

```
Array
(
    [Joy] => Array
        (
            [poll 6] => 16
            [poll 5] => 15
            [poll 4] => 20
            [poll 3] => 21
            [poll 2] => 19
        )

    [Tim] => Array
        (
            [poll 6] => 18
            [poll 5] => 16
            [poll 4] => 15
            [poll 3] => 15
            [poll 2] => 22
        )

    [Sue] => Array
        (
            [poll 6] => 19
            [poll 5] => 14
            [poll 4] => 15
            [poll 3] => 16
            [poll 2] => 19
        )

    [Joe] => Array
        (
            [poll 6] => 17
            [poll 5] => 17
            [poll 4] => 14
            [poll 3] => 14
            [poll 2] => 20
        )

)
```

Hopefully, from there you can figure out how to construct a pretty table using html and/or css.

Comment: I truly appreciate the answer and it's definitely above my skills to completely comprehend - but I will.  I had simplified the question to explain and plugged in my true table and column names  It is not, however, working. I'll build new tables based on your data and dissect it until I understand it.

.You can see the poll I now have,ordered by name, on the right side of this page http://2016.presidential-candidates.org/

Comment: I'm certain this is the answer I'm looking for.  Thank you very much.  It has worked very well as is.  I am still having a little trouble integrating the examples into my original tables but it's just a matter of trial and error.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: Fantastic Strawberry!  If PHP isn't your strong suit, I'd like to see what is.

Not only have I solved the challenge, I've learned a lot.  Thank you.
Results here - http://2016.republican-candidates.org/#polls